# + in base64 with html/template golang

Tags: go, go-html-template

Salutations fellow gophers.

I need to return data matrix in base64 form in an html template.
In template it looks like this.
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{.Datamatrix}}" alt="Datamatrix"/>`

I insert my base64 data in .Datamatrix. And all is fine. Base64 is valid and all(checked on different decoders), however when I pass the data to template `+(plus)` symbols change to `&#43`

Encoding base64 like so:
`base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)`

Tried `base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(b)` too, but then even more symbols get messed up.

Passing param as structure field of type string

Tried passing it different ways: as type `template.HTML`, used `template.HTMLEscapeString`, `template.URLEscapeString`, `template.JSEscapeString` with no result.

Working solution to this problem would be highly appreciated.

Example
https://go.dev/play/p/c_s-wPl6dMT

Related issue on github: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42506

P>S> Changing to text/template is not an option either. In real project I have some more things, that I inject in template, and they simply won't work with text/template lib.

Comment: You should use [`template.URL`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#URL) since this is a known safe URL fragment (after a fashion - it's being used as such anyway since it's going into a `src` attribute).

Comment: It seems to work same way as I encode to base64 with UrlEncode, in that case it messes up bunch of other symbols changing them to _

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. using https://go.dev/play? You currently have so many different things you've tried that it's tough to interpret exactly what you've got going on.

Comment: added example in main message; as for what is going on: From my data I create PNG image, then convert it to base64; this base64 contains + symbols, when I inject my base64 in template those + symbols change to '''&#43''' and base64 can't be decoded

Comment: After further inspection I agree - the fact that this still HTML-encodes the value appears to be a bug: https://go.dev/play/p/qq93kNKSEyW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly enough text/template solved all issues. And didn't cause any new problems with other injections.

https://go.dev/play/p/SsZ9j7WeZ5H